# MutationObserver for when parent changes

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

Is there a way to detect when the parent of an element changes (namely when changing from `null` to `!null` -- i.e., when the element is initially added to the DOM) using a `MutationObserver`? I can't find any documentation that shows how this could be achieved.

I am programmatically creating elements with `document.createElement()`. I return the created element from a function, but want to create a listener from *within* the function to react when the element is eventually added to the DOM, without knowing *where* or *which parent* it will be added to.

---

I'm not quite sure how else to phrase this, honestly.

```
const elem = document.createElement('div');

let added = false;
elem.addEventListener('added-to-dom', () => { added = true; });
// ^ how do I achieve this?

assert(added == false);
document.body.addChild(elem);
assert(added == true);
```

I don't see what's so hard about understanding this or why it was closed.

Comment: What do you mean from `null` to `!null`? If element exists in a DOM than it always have a parent, so you have to precise your question. But with `MutationObserver` basically you can track whatever you want observing a `body` element for example.

Comment: No, MutationObserver can only observe what's documented: child nodes and attributes. The thing you want - detecting when an element is attached to the live DOM - can be implemented via the deprecated DOM mutation events, AFAIK.

Comment: @wOxxOm added clarification.

Comment: Based upon your clarification, isn't your question: _how do I detect when a programmatically created element is added to the DOM_?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to word it, but I was afraid I would get answers like yours that suggest listening to the parent - when I do not know what the parent might be. I wanted to see if this could be done with `MutationObservers` in particular, in which the answer sounds like no. I really don't see how it's this confusing.

Comment: Let's take the case: `const parent = document.createElement('foo'); parent.append(yourElement);` then later... `document.getElementById('bar').append(parent);` Which of these two events do you want to listen to?

Answer (score 2):

An easy but inelegant way is to monkeypatch `Node.prototype.appendChild` (and, if necessary, `Element.prototype.append`, `Element.prototype.insertAdjacentElement`, and `Node.prototype.insertBefore`) to watch for when an element is added to the DOM:

```js
const elementsToWatch = new Set();
const { appendChild } = Node.prototype;
Node.prototype.appendChild = function(childToAppend) {
  if (elementsToWatch.has(childToAppend)) {
    console.log('Watched child appended!');
    elementsToWatch.delete(childToAppend);
  }
  return appendChild.call(this, childToAppend);
};



button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Element created...');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  elementsToWatch.add(div);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('About to append element...');
    container.appendChild(div);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Append something after 1000ms</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Mutating built-in prototypes generally isn't a good idea, though.

Another option would be to use a MutationObserver for the *whole document*, but this may well result in lots of activated callbacks for a large page with frequent mutations, which may not be desirable:

```js
const elementsToWatch = [];
new MutationObserver(() => {
  // instead of the below, another option is to iterate over elements
  // observed by the MutationObserver
  // which could be more efficient, depending on how often
  // other elements are added to the page
  const root = document.documentElement; // returns the <html> element
  const indexOfElementThatWasJustAdded = elementsToWatch.findIndex(
    elm => root.contains(elm)
  );
  // instead of the above, could also use `elm.isConnected()` on newer browsers
  
  // if an appended node, if it has a parent,
  // will always be in the DOM,
  // instead of `root.contains(elm)`, can use `elm.parentElement`

  if (indexOfElementThatWasJustAdded === -1) {
    return;
  }
  elementsToWatch.splice(indexOfElementThatWasJustAdded, 1);
  console.log('Observed an appended element!');
}).observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });


button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Element created...');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = 'foo';
  elementsToWatch.push(div);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('About to append element...');
    container.appendChild(div);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Append something after 1000ms</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: `closest()` seems quite expensive here, you could shortcut by checking `.parentNode`, and even just  [`isConnected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected) (I'm still not sure what OP wants between parentNode change and isConnected). Also, there would be other methods to override like `insertBefore`, `insertAdjacentHTML`, `replaceChild`, etc. Finally, why observe only the body? OP may very well produce elements they'll append to the head too.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the element had a possibility of being appended to something else before it was inserted into the page - if so, the `.closest` (or `.contains`) is needed, otherwise, yeah, `parentElement` is fine. `insertAdjacentHTML` only inserts *text*, not elements, right? One can only have a reference to an element (and thereby do something with it) if the actual element exists

Comment: Oh, `isConnected` is handy, I hadn't heard of that one before!

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) I meant.

Comment: Thinking about it once more, for IE>9 but that don't support `isConnected`, we can make a *polyfill*(?) using [`compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition): `if(!("isConnected" in Node.prototype)) {
  Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, 'isConnected', { 
    get: function() {
      return (this.ownerDocument.compareDocumentPosition(this) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED) === 0;
    }
  })
}`. Note though that I didn't really checked the specs for isConnected and there might be cases where this will break...

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for the `DOMNodeInserted`-event and compare the elements id.

> **Notice:** *This event is marked as **Depricated** and will probably stop working in modern modern browsers at some point in the near
>   future.*

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let button = document.getElementById('button');

document.body.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
  if (event.originalTarget.id == button.id) {
    console.log('Parent changed to: ' + event.originalTarget.parentElement.id);
  }
});

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  container.appendChild(button);
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 140px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed #c0a;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="button">append to container</button>
```

Comment: Yeah I was afraid this was the only way :/ Sad they deprecated something without any replacement 'proper' way.